# ngrx 5.2 MetaReducer type mismatch

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm trying the new ngRx v5.2, setup everything fine (reducers, action). But by the time I initialized my store by StoreModule.forRoot(reducers,{metaReducer}). I'm getting an error below:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(32,35): 
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ metaReducer: MetaReducer<State, Action>[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreConfig<State, Action>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'metaReducer' does not exist in type 'StoreConfig<State, Action>'.
```

./store/index.ts

```
...
export interface State {
  fileUpload:       fromAppFeature1.State;
  //TODO more to add here
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  feature1:   fromAppFeature1.reducer
  //TODO more to add here
};


export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return function(state: State, action: any):State {
    console.log('state', state);
    console.log('action', action);
    return reducer(state, action);
  }

}

export const metaReducer: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [logger, storeFreeze] : [];
```

problem occurs I think since version 4, I'm not sure why this still not fixed. What should I do to mitigate this type error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you misspelled the property. It should be `metaReducers` not `metaReducer` (note there should be an `s` on the end) https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/7f49b9f413471306d614cd5eae8b4e8d7e41f611/modules/store/src/store_module.ts#L88

Comment: Whoa! that solves the problem. Probably I don't completely understand typescript, but how does user defined const metaReducer won't work while metaReducers works? Thank you for the response!

Comment: In TypeScript, `{  variable }` is short hand for `{ variable: variable }`. If you have your variable the same name as your property name you can use the short hand way, otherwise you will have to do the regular way.

Comment: `export const metaReducer: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [logger, storeFreeze] : [];` 
in that statement `metaReducer` is my define constants I could name it like `rootStore` or something. How come making it `metaReducers` _(with 's')_ works and not other name.

Comment: For the exact reason I described. The `StoreConfig` type needs a `metaReducers` property on it. The error you received in your question stated that it received a `metaReducer` property instead. I deduced from your code that you were setting the `StoreConfig` like `{ metaReducer }`. You can call your variable whatever you want, but if you don't want to name it the same as the property in question (`metaReducers`), you will have to set the `StoreConfig` like this: `{ metaReducers: whateverVariableNameYouWantToUse }`

Comment: Thank you very much it is much clearer now.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code please, I am having the same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445678/getting-error-while-setting-reducers-type-metareducerstate-action-is-not