# Getting error while setting reducers: Type 'MetaReducer<State, Action>[]' is not assignable to type 'MetaReducer<unknown, Action>[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting the following error while attempting to set up my reducers in app.module.ts

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:72:7 - error TS2322: Type 'MetaReducer<State, Action>[]' is not assignable to type 'MetaReducer<unknown, Action>[]'.
  Types of parameters 'reducer' and 'reducer' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'State'.

72       metaReducers,
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I fix it? My code is as follows:

```
const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [logger] : [];

interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<BaseRouterStoreState>;
}

const reducers: ActionReducerMap<unknown> = {};

function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return (state: State | undefined, action: Action): State => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
    console.log('prev state', state);
    console.log('action', action);
    console.log('next state', result);
    console.groupEnd();
    return result;
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      // TS2322: Type 'MetaReducer<State, Action>[]' is not assignable to type 'MetaReducer<unknown, Action>[]'. Types of parameters 'reducer' and 'reducer' are incompatible. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'State'.
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```